# relacion bidireccional entre tablas?

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, diseño

estoy diseñando el esquema de unas tablas de usuario y Cursos/Seminarios/charlas; en la cual un usuario puede tener múltiples cursos estos cursos están en una lista de Cursos; esta parte ya esta relacionada; pero ahora me veo en la necesidad de diseñar una tabla de pre-requisitos; el problema que esto supone es que algunos cursos no tienen prerrequisitos y que los que tienen prerrequisito son cursos que están en la misma lista de cursos.. ***¿Cómo planteo esta relaciona bidireccional?*** este es el diseño del esquema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo utilizaría una tabla auxiliar para guardar las relaciones entre un curso y sus prerrequisitos. Simplemente la ID del curso principal en una columna y en una segunda columna la id del curso que es prerrequisito suyo

Comment: @Benito-B mira esto es lo que tengo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HFYUW7dKQP_pgg3sv6IVQdPq9fCVWWlA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Benito-B me puedes ayudar estoy aprendiendo a usar work-bench ...

Comment: Suena a que tu tabla de requisitos es una tabla pivote para la relación *n* a *n* entre la tabla cursos y ella misma.

Comment: si es algo asi... pero no se como se debe plantear ficha relacion usando las herramientas de mysql workbench